# Session is being killed before it should be

Tags: php

So I thought I'd control when a session ends, and it's not turning out as planned. I'm not sure why.

Rather than dumping all my code, I thought I'd share what I believe to be the most relavent. If more is needed please let me know:

UserManagement.php:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the user is still active, and acts accordingly.
/// </summary>
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
    $secondsOfInactivity = 18000;

    $sessionLife = time() - $_SESSION['LastActive'];
    if($sessionLife > $secondsOfInactivity)
    {
        SignOut();
    }

    //if(time() - $_SESSION['LastActive'] > 180)
    //{
    //    // User has been inactive for 3 minutes. Sign them out.
    //    SignOut();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    $_SESSION['LastActive'] = time();
    //}
}

function SignedIn()
{        
    return boolval($_SESSION['SI']) == true ? true : false;
}//...
```

SignIn.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once 'Configuration.php';
    require_once 'UserManagement.php';

    echo SignedIn() ? 'Hi' : 'Bye';//...
```

UserManagement.php:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to return an authenticated user.
/// </summary>
function SignIn($emailAddress, $password)
{
    $user = ORM::for_table('Users')->where_equal('EmailAddress', $emailAddress)->where_equal('Password', sha1($password))->find_one();

    if($user != null)
    {
        $_SESSION['SI'] = true;

        $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $user->get('FirstName');
        $_SESSION['LastName'] = $user->get('LastName');
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $user->get('EmailAddress');
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user->get('UserID');

        $_SESSION['LastActive'] = time();

        $user = null;
    }
    else
    {
        SignOut();
    }

    return $_SESSION['SI'];
}
```

The problem I'm having is that although `secondsOfInactivity` is set to a high number, the moment I refresh the page or click a link, the session is no longer active and I am logged out. I don't know why I'm being logged out.

If I remove the code that destroys the session after a period has elapsed, I remain logged in as expected. But why is it logging me out sooner than it should?

Comment: Difficult to see what's going on with the code you've given, but make sure that you're not calling your `SignIn` function on each page as that is set to log you out if `$user` is null. Check any other places you call `SignOut` as well.

Comment: you need to sign in _before_ you access LastActive for the first time. also, turn notices on (error_reporting), that should yield you an undefined notice…

Comment: @bwoebi I added a check in UserManagement to ensure that the session timeout code only gets executed _if_ the user is already signed in. It's now working as expected. Thank you.